# How to setup stripe recurring payments after migrate from paypal?

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions, stripe

Stripe has acquired all the recurring payment profile from Paypal. But Stripe support team were not able to help setting up recurring payments and connect to existing payment profile on CiviCRM. Can anyone have a clue a best way of connecting stripe to CiviCRM please?